# replacing text in app.config using powershell script

Tags: teamcity, powershell-2.0, replace

I am trying a simple replace script to replace text in a app.cofig file. But it just processed and do nothing:

```
$old = 'Z:\gene'
$new = 'z:\gene\scripts'
Get-ChildItem z:\gene\scripts\Test\App.config -Recurse | Where {$_ -IS [IO.FileInfo]} |
% {
(Get-Content $_.FullName) -replace $old,$new | Set-Content $_.FullName
Write-Host "Processed: " + $_.FullName
}
```

Any Idea what I am doing wrong. As same script works fine for .txt file
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

App.config is xml formatted but it's a text file as well, it should work the same.  My guess is that you have a different values that your working on and they are not hitting.  If you rename the file to app.txt does it work ?  You might also consider using nant xmlpoke if you are running from nant script.

Comment: yes checked..Seems it is not scripting the path drives while replacing. If you use simple text instead of z: then it works. Any idea how to replace the full path as well.